# how to read these specific line in java

Tags: java, file-io, csv, io, java.util.scanner

i have a csv file like this:

```
i,0             <-- 1st line  
f,1,2,3         <-- 2nd line  
s,0,1,2,3,4,5,6 <-- 3rd line  
0,1,A  
0,5,B  
1,1,A  
1,3,B  
2,6,A  
2,4,B  
3,6,A  
3,4,B  
4,6,A  
4,4,B  
5,1,A  
5,5,B  
6,6,A  
6,2,B
```

how do i read these line to 4 different array/arraylist in java?
the output i want is something like this:

- 1st line: 0 [1st array]
- 2nd line: 1 2 3 [2nd array] --> just 1 line but the length of the token is unknown
- 3rd line: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 [3rd array]  --> just 1 line but the length of the token is unknown
- rest of the line:  --> fixed 3 token, but the number of the row is unknown
  0 1 A
  0 5 B
  1 1 A
  1 3 B
  2 6 A
  2 4 B
  3 6 A
  3 4 B
  4 6 A
  4 4 B
  5 1 A
  5 5 B
  6 6 A
  6 2 B

can't get it right with the combination of scanner and switch-case condition..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use `switch`. Just read the file line by line. If the file is generated (or you are otherwise sure that it is correct) than you could read it like

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(...));
array1 = readFirstLine(reader);
array2 = readSecondLine(reader);
array3 = readThirdLine(reader);
// and so on
```

and implement every `read...` method to handle one line format.

**Update:** The read methods could look something like

```
private String[] readFirstLine(BufferedReader reader) {
    String line = reader.readLine();
    String[] fields = line.split(",");
    return fields;
}
```

Comment: how to implement every read method to handle one line format?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Scanner's [nextLine](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) to read the lines. Since you specifically want the 1st, 2nd and 3rd line to belong to the 1st, 2nd and 3rd arrays respectively, you can call read 3 times and then use String's [split](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) method to populate the array. Once you are done, you can create a loop and populate the arraylist in which way you want.

So basically: Read and Split (for each of the first 3 lines) and then read and populate in a loop for the rest of the file.